# run async db read task in background

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have function called `get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll` where I want to call it in the background 10 times/minute and refresh  new systems that I have gotten in last 10 seconds.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


async def create_state_machine_at_init(app):

    worker_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    worker = Thread(target=start_db_worker, args=(worker_loop,))
    worker.start()

    worker_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll, app, 30)


async def get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll(app, interval=10):
    params = {
        param: key
        for param, key
        in app.config.get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll_params.items()
        }
    params['interval'] = interval

    operation = prepare_exec(
        app.config.get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll,
        **params
        )
    ACTIVE_ALLOWED_SYSTEMS
    ACTIVE_ALLOWED_SYSTEMS = (await app['database'].execute(operation)).all()
    return ACTIVE_ALLOWED_SYSTEMS

def start_db_worker(loop):
    """Switch to new event loop and run forever"""

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
```

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:145: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll' was never awaited

Comment: `call_soon_threadsafe` accept a callback, but not an async function

Comment: You should wrap `get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll` to function scheduler. e.g. `def scheduler(): asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(get_active_allowed_systems_by_poll())` and pass it to `call_soon_threadsafe` as callback

Comment: Also you could use [run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead of `call_soon_threadsafe`